# How to invoke ondeletecommand of a DataList inside another

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a datalist containing usercontrol placed in update panel, any of these usercontrols  may contain a datalist.I'm trying to fire ondeletecommand of the inside datalist but nothing happens.Any clue

Answer (score 1):

Did you hook the OnDeleteCommand in the user control containing the data list? Each container will fire their own respective events

Comment: Of course I did and it works fine on its own.The problem is: it is contained in a nested datalist, firing the innermost onitemcommand nothing happens.

Comment: Just checking, do you add the user controls in markup or in code behind?